# Generate XSD File from an XML with xmltype in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: java, xml, oracle, plsql, xsd

My desired outcome is to get an XSD file generated from an XML straight in oracle

I'm using an SQL query in a PL/SQL procedure to generate an XMLType from a table.

With that XMLtype I then do a .GetClobVal() and return the clob version of that which I am currently copying into the following online tool
[http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output) and then am able to generate an XSD out of this.

I know that this XSD is not perfect and will not be exactly how I want it, but it is pretty close.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a tool in Oracle that can do this, I can only find this for [generating XSD from an Oracle type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlsch.htm#i1009760), but I don't use an Oracle Type in this situation, so **please do not suggest using one**.

Here is a sample of the code I use to create xml

```
With  Accounts As  (  Select  XMLAgg(
                              XMLElement("AccountDetail",
                                XMLForest(1234    || Level  As "UID",
                                          'Test'  || Level  As "Name"))) As xmlData,
                              Count(*) as dataCount
                      From    Dual
                      Connect By Level <= 2
               )
Select  XMLElement("GetAccountDataResponse",
          XMLElement("ResponseInfo",
            XMLElement("Code",            'Success'),
            XMLElement("Message",         'Normal Successful Completion'),
            XMLElement("DebugInfo",
              XMLElement("DBVersion",     'V01.01.00'))),
            Accounts.xmlData
        ).GetClobVal()
From    Accounts;
```

Here is the XML sample:

```
<GetAccountDataResponse>
  <ResponseInfo>
    <Code>Success</Code>
    <Message>Normal Successful Completion</Message>
    <DebugInfo>
      <DBVersion>V01.01.00</DBVersion>
    </DebugInfo>
  </ResponseInfo>
  <AccountDetail>
    <UID>12341</UID>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
  </AccountDetail>
  <AccountDetail>
    <UID>12342</UID>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
  </AccountDetail>
</GetAccountDataResponse>
```

When you copy the code into the xsd-generator that I mentioned earlier, you get the output of:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="GetAccountDataResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResponseInfo">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Code"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message"/>
              <xs:element name="DebugInfo">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DBVersion"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="AccountDetail" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="UID"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Which is pretty close and would allow me to do a replace on type="xs:short" to type="xs:int" within PL/SQL etc to get my desired outputs.

I would also be happy if there was a JAVA program that could do this, as Oracle has the support for running JAVA natively

Comment: Anyone able to help at all?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Oracle Tool that generate XSD from an XML.

You can try this Apache XMLBeans inst2xsd tool: http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd